# CSS Background-image on a-tag not displaying in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background

I have researched this and found some IE CSS bugs, but none of the known fixes seem to cover this scenario.

This site went live today and the issue that was found is that the logo does not display in SOME versions of IE8.  If the person resets IE to factory settings it works, but otherwise the logo is invisible.

Site can be seen here:  http://www.ethicsgame.com/exec/site/index.html

CSS to display the logo is

```
h1 a {

background:url(images/logosmall.gif) no-repeat left center;
padding-left:325px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#1f396d;
position:relative;
top:45px;
left:15px;
width: 325px;
```

}

Comment: I looked into all the answers here and none of these suggestions worked.  I have since removed it from the css background tag and placed the image directly into the html.  Thanks for the comments on the html, I hadn't realized some of the other odd syntax, which I've since cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be working fine on my IE8, have your tried adding `display: inline-block` to its css? Also, for good measure you could throw a `&nbsp;` inside the a tag.

so you get:

```
<h1><a href="index.html">&nbsp;</a></h1>
```

just so it has content...

good luck -ck

Comment: Using inline-block should fix the situation. It fixed it when I ran IE as IE7 (it wasn't showing up then).  But you'll have to do some other things to address the "Schedule a Demo" element from dropping down when you do that.

Comment: yeah there seems to be some issues with the html in there, i see a `<div>` inside of an `<a>` tag which is strange to say the least. And the `<a>` tag in question actually has nothing giving it height what-so-ever, so as an `inline` element it should have just collapsed... strange it didn't.  I also am wondering why not just shove an `<img>` inside that `<a>`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a difference in spacing with IE8 vs Chrome. Check it out in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vt3f/.

Basically your image is probably displaying, just too far to the left that it's not visible.

Also, you have "left" and "center" on the image. This is conflicting. It's either left or center.

Answer (score 0):

Mary,

This has to do with the fact that A tags are inline elements.  in IE < 8, the height/width of the element isn't getting rendered--so it's collapsing and becoming invisible.  Adding `display: block;` into your CSS declaration for this element will fix this in IE < 8.  You'll want to apply this same principle to other inline elements that you're trying to get to behave more like block-level elements (setting width/height/margin/padding is usually a good hint on this behavior).

If you don't need to support IE 5.5 (which most people don't nowadays), you can also use `display: inline-block;` (keep in mind that IE 6-7 only support inline-block on elements that are natually inline elements, such as A, SPAN, STRONG, EM, etc.).  You can find much helpful compatibility information here:
http://quirksmode.org/css/display.html

You'll probbaly also notice that once you change that display type, the padding which isn't being rendered will be--so you might need to change that markup a bit to compensate.

Using the Developer Toolbar in IE is a great way to test old versions, as well as test these solutions in the older versions.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly alright on IE8 but if does not show earlier versions of IE then replace **center** with **left** in background attribute.

```
background:url(images/logosmall.gif) no-repeat center left;
```

Answer (score 0):

ie8 doesn't support background image position, in your case "left center".  If you remove "center left" it should work.  You might be able to specify background image position if you specify !DOCTYPE